# Phrasal adjectives

Tags: grammaticality

1.It was none other than John. 
2. It was told by no less than John. 
In both the example sentences above, can the phrase "none other than" &"no less than" be said to be used adjectivally emphasising the noun 'John'.

Comment: The usual expression is 'no less a person than [John]'.

Comment: Dear Kate, thanks for responding though you have not addressed my specific query on adjectival use of the phrase.

Comment: Well, I suppose it's a sort of adjective in that it 'describes' John by implying that he's an important person.

Comment: By the way "no lesser person than John" is also possible